# Google Sheets получение значения другого листа по условию

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet, excel-формулы

Мне необходимо вывести значение из одного листа на другом листе. Я получаю адрес ячейки, где лежит нужное значение, но ни как не могу получить само значение.

Моя формула:

`=ДВССЫЛ("P&L!"&TO_TEXT(АДРЕС(60; ПОИСКПОЗ(ДАТА(ГОД(СЕГОДНЯ()); МЕСЯЦ(СЕГОДНЯ()); 1);'P&L'!A2:AI2);4)))`

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Зачем так сложно? Не надо преобразовывать номер колонки в адрес, адрес в текст, текст в ячейку... Для поиска связанных значений есть специальные функции - например, `=HLOOKUP(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()); MONTH(TODAY()); 1);'P&L'!$A$2:$AI$60;59;1)` или `=LOOKUP(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()); MONTH(TODAY()); 1);'P&L'!$A$2:$AI$2;'P&L'!$A$60:$AI$60)`. Но в последнее время всё чаще рекомендуют что-то вроде `=INDEX('P&L'!$A$60:$AI$60;MATCH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()); MONTH(TODAY()); 1);'P&L'!$A$2:$AI$2;1))` (такой поиск хоть и сложнее в записи, но гибче в использовании). А ещё есть `OFFSET()` - тоже может подойти

Comment: `СМЕЩ (OFFSET()`, как и `ДВССЫЛ` - функция летучая и применять ее без крайней надобности не нужно. *@Rumeet*, покажите на примере, что хотите получить - возможно, получите другие решения.

Comment: @JohnSUN спасибо Вам большое